# How to redirect to another url using apache vhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, apache2, vhosts

I have installed wordpress on my machine. I have two direcotory for apache to serve websites.

first is `/var/www/html/wordpressone` & second is `/var/www/html/wordpresstwo`. Now i able to access these to sites using below url

```
http://192.168.0.1/wordpressone -> /var/www/html/wordpressone
http://192.168.0.1/wordpresstwo -> /var/www/html/wordpresstwo
```

Now i want define a custom url eg.

```
http://192.168.0.1/admin -> /var/www/html/wordpressone
http://192.168.0.1/user -> /var/www/html/wordpresstwo
```

But i am not able to do it using Vhost. I tried below method but did not work.

I created a file `home.conf` under  `/etc/apache2/sites-available` & enabled it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://192.168.0.1/user
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpressone
<Directory />
```

Please tell me what are steps i need to perform to achieve this ?

Comment: Can't you just rename the folders? If you must do it through Apache, you can use [aliases](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html). But that would be a very complex solution to a very simple problem (that would be solved by just renaming the folders).

Comment: I think you are missing the point of a VH! With a `ServerName wpone.test` you will be able to access `/var/www/html/wordpressone` with a simple, fairly normal URL. Note you will have to add a line into your HOSTS file

Comment: You should also install INTO the Virtual Host, so that WP's odd desire to save the url it was installed into into its database. Or there are WP tutorials on how to change the database when moving sites

Comment: No i don't want to rename the folders. That's not a solution

Comment: Why do you want to use a URL with an ip address in it?

Comment: _"No i don't want to rename the folders. That's not a solution"_ - From what you ask in your question, it's definitely a solution. If you give us some more info into why you say it isn't, it might be easier for us to find a solution that fits you. Right now, it just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I don't have purchased domain. For learnign purpose i want to know how apache identify a url from request and rediect to another url

Comment: But what you're trying to do has nothing to do with domains and isn't something you probably will ever do "for real". It will probably be way more useful to look into what @RiggsFolly suggested in his first comment. Add a couple of fake host names into your HOSTS file and set up two proper vhosts with those instead. Like `admin.test`  and `user.test`.

Comment: ___I don't have purchased domain___ You dont need a real domain. ASsume you might call the real site `xxx.in` you can locally create a VH and call it `xxx.test`. Then things will work almost exactly like they will when you move a site LIVE. If this is just for learning, **it is still nice to have a sensible domain name**

Comment: I tried with fake domain names. What i did is added user.example.com and admin.example.com into /etc/hosts. And also created separated .conf file for user and admin.It works for me well. But i wanted if i specify path as user.example.com/user it should redirect to some other path.

Answer (score 0):

All Depends on Document Root. It Navigates you to the given folder Just Make two host one with

```
http://192.168.0.1/admin
```

with the configuration inside

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://192.168.0.1/admin
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpressone
<Directory />
```

and another with

```
http://192.168.0.1/user
```

with the configuration inside

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://192.168.0.1/user
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpresstwo
<Directory />
```